# Susy grid: make not fluid from specific width

Tags: static, grid, sass, media-queries, susy-compass

I'm using Omega 4 for Drupal and with it the Susy grid system (and sass and compass).

The entire Susy grid is great and scales fluidly. However it doesn't look good when the window gets too narrow.

How do I make the susy grid have a static width for all screen sizes below 800px?

I'm not looking to make the entire system full responsive, so just fixed width below 800px would be sufficient.

Comment: Depends how your project is set up. How many grid breakpoints do you have, at what sizes?

Comment: @EricMeyer

No breakpoints used so far.

This is my column width setup:

`$total-columns  : 12;             // a 12-column grid
$column-width   : 7em;            
$gutter-width   : 0em;            
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width;  `

Ideally, i could use something simple like: if screen size < 800, set $column-width to "66px". But can't figure out how to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of messing with grid-settings at different widths, apply a `min-width` to your container:

```
.container {
  @include container;
  min-width: 800px;
}
```

That gets a bit more complex if you have multiple breakpoints, and want multiple min-widths, but it should work for you case.